# how to program a 5 pin motor with raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am recently working on a project where i want to control  a 5 pin servo motor with raspberry pi.

[image: 5 Pin servo motor]

i have searched for resources and found adafruit's servo motor with only 3 pin.This is link for [Adafruit's 3 pin servo motor](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-8-using-a-servo-motor)

**Problem** :

What's difference between a 5 pin and 3 pin servo motor ?
If they both are same what's pin out diagram for this 5 pin servo motor ?

This is source code for 3 pin servo motor.

```
    # Servo Control
import time
def set(property, value):
try:
f = open("/sys/class/rpi-pwm/pwm0/" + property, 'w')
f.write(value)
f.close()   
except:
print("Error writing to: " + property + " value: " + value)
 
 
def setServo(angle):
set("servo", str(angle))
set("delayed", "0")
set("mode", "servo")
set("servo_max", "180")
set("active", "1")
 
delay_period = 0.01
 
while True:
for angle in range(0, 180):
setServo(angle)
time.sleep(delay_period)
for angle in range(0, 180):
setServo(180 - angle)
time.sleep(delay_period)
```

What modifications must I do to control a 5 pin servo motor? Are there any major modifications?

Comment: If you don't know the differences in pin outs between 3 & 5 pin, how can we?  So, that should be your question (in a hardware forum)

Comment: Well i dont know the pin out for 5 pin because i borrowed it from my friend's project and the worst part is even he does'nt know the pin out it was a ready project !!! i guess you know what i am trying to tell and also i tried to google for a 5 pin servo motor pinout but could not find any... could you please give a link for hardware forum you told about.. and thanks for info.

Comment: You could try asking your hardware related questions, about the servo motor and how to physically connect it to your Raspberry Pi on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ You'll need to provide more details though. If possible give the manufacturer and model number of your specific motor. Failing that find what exact project kit your friend bought and maybe they can figure it out from that. Keep your question hardware focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a servo. It's a 5 pin Stepper motor you also need uni-polar driver

Comment: Can i connect this to pi and install uni-polar driver so that i can continue my project further with this stepper motor or do i need to buy a new servo motor for pi ?

Comment: You need to buy a 180 degree servo

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, well u can connect a stepper motor or servo motor or dc motor for your Raspbberi Pi.
Check the link for adafruit's stepper motor connection to raspberry pi.

[Raspberry Pi stepper motor connection](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-10-stepper-motors/overview)

If u see some more lessons you will find that you can connect dc,stepper or servo motor to your Pi.